# Spring Cloud Stream message is not received through message queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, reactor

I have 2 microservices(images and comments) which communicate one with another(discovered by eureka discovery service) using Spring Cloud Stream with broker rabbit mq. I want to send a message from images microservice to comment microservice.
The problem is that CommentController StreamListener method 'save' is not called.

Image Microservice-> CommentController.java:

```
public CommentController(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
    this.flux = Flux.<Message<Comment>>create(
            emitter -> this.commentSink = emitter,
            FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.IGNORE)
            .publish()
            .autoConnect();
}
@PostMapping("/comments")
public Mono<String> addComment(Mono<Comment> newComment) {
    if (commentSink != null) {
        return newComment
            .map(comment -> {
                commentSink.next(MessageBuilder
                    .withPayload(comment)
                    .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .build());
                return comment;
            })
            .flatMap(comment -> {
                meterRegistry
                    .counter("comments.produced", "imageId", comment.getImageId())
                    .increment();
                return Mono.just("redirect:/");
            });
    } else {
        return Mono.just("redirect:/");
    }
}
    @StreamEmitter
@Output(Source.OUTPUT)
public void emit(FluxSender output) {
    output.send(this.flux);
}
```

Comment Microservice -> CommentService.java

```
@StreamListener
@Output(Processor.OUTPUT)
public Flux<Void> save(@Input(Processor.INPUT) Flux<Comment> newComment) {
    return repository
        .saveAll(newComment)
        .flatMap(comment -> {
            meterRegistry
                .counter("comments.consumed", "imageId", comment.getImageId())
                .increment();
            return Mono.empty();
        });
}
```

CommentService.java->`@Service
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class CommentService { ....`

[Repository which I cloned Chapter7/part 1](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learning-Spring-Boot-2.0-Second-Edition/tree/master/Chapter06/part3/src/main/java/com/greglturnquist/learningspringboot)

[Image Microservice -> CommentController.java](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learning-Spring-Boot-2.0-Second-Edition/blob/master/Chapter07/part1/images/src/main/java/com/greglturnquist/learningspringboot/images/ImageService.java)

[Comment Microservice -> CommentService.java](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learning-Spring-Boot-2.0-Second-Edition/blob/master/Chapter07/part1/images/src/main/java/com/greglturnquist/learningspringboot/images/CommentController.java)

Comment: What makes you believe that it has to be invoked? I do not see any connection between `addComment(..)` and `save(..)`. As far as the code goes they are completely independent services. The `addComment(..)` appears to be an HTTP endpoint and `save(..)` is a listener subscribing to "input" channel/destination. Also, your CommentService.java link is broken

Comment: I edited the code. I thought that using the emit() method the flux would get written to Source.OUTPUT